# How to do some specific background task every second in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, background-process

I have a react-redux app. My redux store contains a `2D boolean list i.e. parking` where each cell is initialised with some random integer.

I want to run a background process that runs every second and execute the following function

```
function substractParking(){
    for(all cells i,j in array){
        if(parking[i][j] !== 0){
            parking[i][j] -= 1
        }
    }
}
```

I thought about this and came across two possible solutions.

1. Every second I will dispatch an action that will execute the above code, but this will slow my application. I can do this.
2. Somehow I can store a class in redux store which will auto run this code every second i.e. my redux store will have a class rather than 2D boolean array. But I don't know how to do this.
3. Some background process, but again I don't know how to create a backgroung process in react-redux.

What is the best way to do this? I can only code the solution 1 and I don't know how solution 2 and 3 can be achieved.

Comment: What about `web-worker`s ?

Answer (score 0):

(1) is what makes sense to me. Slow the application, or, better put, load the CPU? Any way to do it without loading the CPU?

Comment: load the CPU. That's what I am asking here, is there any better way to do background tasks rather than just calling an action every second.

Comment: But in your question you wrote that "I want to run a background process that runs every second and execute the following function"... I thought that this was your requirement...